Does the series $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{1+(p_n^2\pmod{n^2})}$ converge or diverge?
Is it possible to prove convergence or divergence of the series $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{1+(p_n^2\pmod{n^2})}$$
being $p_n$ the n-th prime?
For $n=100$ the sum is $$2.816445677903807$$
For $n=200$ $$2.837324254568231$$
For $n=300$ $$2.8476522370914625$$
For $n=400$ $$3.056819760530698$$
For $n=500$ $$3.059051271417232$$
For $n=600$ $$3.0620787054116723$$
For $n=700$ $$3.0630795010469054$$
For $n=800$ $$3.0650989648952502$$
For $n=900$ $$3.067456193195979$$
For $n=1000$ $$3.0682069161257437$$
Many thanks.

is $p_n$ is nth prime ?

Plugging Willans formula : $$p_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \left\lfloor \left(\frac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^i \left\lfloor\left(\cos \frac{(j-1)! + 1}{j} \pi\right)^2\right\rfloor }\right)^{1/n} \right\rfloor$$ may help.

@EDX that most certainly won't help

This exercise seems non-trivial at all because it demands that we want $p_n^2 \mod n^2$ to high enough close to $n^2$ to get the convergence.
So your question is equivalent to seeking the distance between $p_n^{2} \mod n^2$ and $n^2$ as $n$ goes big. Noting so the rest of $p_n^2$ divided by $n^2$ as $r_n$ and the quotient $q_n$ such that :
$$ p_n^2=q_nn^2+r_n $$ which kind of demanding the repartition of the squared prime numbers $\mod n$. I'm not enough experienced in arithmetic to conclude that we may need Riemann hypothesis and some results by it gives me the impression to do so.
